# Unable to view Waterfall charts on private instance of webpagetest

Tags: php, performance-testing

I have set up a private instance of webpagetest on my Windows 7 machine. It works well with the exception of not displaying the waterfall charts and screenshots. All I see are little placeholder icons and spinners. I am using PHP version 5.6.3. This version of php has GD for graphics and Zip configuration. I looked in php.ini and did not see php_zip or php5_zip. Maybe I need to install one of these? Not sure how to do that. Any advice would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What does the install checker page say - `http://your-webpagetest-server/install`

Normally the lack of waterfall charts and screenshots is due to an issue with GD.